# Second fuction executes before the first fuction is completely executed

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I have two functions fetchData() and setDataUI(), in fetchData() i'm sending a request and saving the response. In setDataUI() function i'm setting adapter to bind the data's.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.image_recycler_view);
        data_list = new ArrayList<>();

        fetchData2(1);
}
```

fetchData2() to fetch data from server.

```
public void fetchData2(final int next){
        String url = Constants.URL+"image/gallery?page="+next;
        Log.d(TAG,"Data2 Url-->"+url);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Response-->" + response);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("media");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Media Array-->" + jsonArray);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        ImageGallery imageGallery = new ImageGallery(
                                jsonObject1.getString("file"),
                                jsonObject1.getString("description"),
                                jsonObject.getInt("next"));

                        data_list.add(imageGallery);

                        Log.d(TAG, "Data List in AsyncTask-->" + data_list);
                        setDataUI();

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityImageGallery.this, "Server Error!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

then in setDataUI()

```
 private void setDataToUI() {
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,1);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        Log.d(TAG,"Data_List-->"+data_list);

        adapter = new AdapterImageGallery(this, data_list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (gridLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == data_list.size()-1){
                    fetchData2(data_list.get(data_list.size()-1).getNext());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Expected Result:
function setDataUI() must only start when fetchData2() finishes execution completely. So, data_list in setDataUI() will have the values that are initialized in fetchData2().

Actual Result :
currently setDataUI() starts execution before fetchData2() completes its execution, resulting in data_list to be empty in setDataUI().

I do get the correct response from the server but after the setDataUI() is executed.

Comment: Call `setDataToUI()` method in `onResponse()` of `fetchData2()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is just change like below in your response method,

```
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    if(response.isSuccessful){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Response-->" + response);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("media");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Media Array-->" + jsonArray);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        ImageGallery imageGallery = new ImageGallery(
                                jsonObject1.getString("file"),
                                jsonObject1.getString("description"),
                                jsonObject.getInt("next"));

                        data_list.add(imageGallery);

                        Log.d(TAG, "Data List in AsyncTask-->" + data_list);
                        }
                       setDataToUI();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

-Put setDataToUI(); method call after completion of your for loop in onresponse. 
-Also, your second method gets executed before your first method because, your first method is asynchronous (i.e., working on another thread. It's not executing in the Main Thread or UI thread).

Answer (score 0):

Volleys' requests are aynchronous. So, you should call your `setDataToUI` from callback:

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                 // all your code

                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                         @Override
                         public void run() {
                               setDataToUI();
                         }
                   }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because in your `fetchData()` Async Task is running in background which you cannot predict how much time it will take. So rather than calling `setDataToUI()` after `fetchData2()` function you can just call it inside the response of the `fetchData2()` function. You can edit this in fetchData2 Function

`data_list.add(imageGallery);
Log.d(TAG, "Data List in AsyncTask-->" + data_list);
setDataToUI()`